# Prevent scrolling due to overflow in non-scrollable elements

Tags: html, scroll, overflow

It's hard to explain the issue, as this seems more like a cross-browser bug than it does a feature. Follow the steps here to see the issue:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run code snippet.
2. Click in textbox.
3. Repeatedly press right-arrow key until text cursor passes edge of box.
4. At this point the box will start 'scrolling' (in spite of the `overflow: hidden`). The grey background element that should fill the box 'slides' left, and to the right of it the white background behind can then be seen.

Desired behavior:

When going out of box, the text cursor simply escapes view, and the box scroll position *does not slide* to compensate.

---

How can I disable this 'no scrollbar' scrolling effect? (Note, it is in fact scrolling, because the js `scrollLeft` value of the `overflow-box` actually changes, even without a scrollbar.)

A CSS solution would really be ideal (e.g., a *working* `overflow: hidden`), but a Javascript solution could still suffice.

```css
.overflow-box {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}
.textbox {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-box">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <input type="text" value="aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj kk ll mm nn oo" class="textbox"/>
</div>
```

I apologize if this question is a duplicate. I cannot find a similar question since I don't know what the effect is called..

TIA!

Comment: If you reduce the width of the input to hit the edge of the parent div, that would solve the issue ..  This can be done manually, or by calculating what the width should be with JS.

Comment: Thanks @Zak. I understand that. That will help some people, but in my project it's actually not this simple. I'll have many inputs that float partly or completely out of the container. I'm looking for a solution that makes the container prevent scrolling whilst being agnostic about its contents. Since `overflow: hidden` doesn't actually prevent scrolling, CSS needs a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I discovered two things:

1. The issue only occurs on elements with `overflow: hidden`
2. When 'scrolling', the box emits the `scroll` event when changing, allowing one to do the following to prevent the scrolling:

```
document.querySelector('.overflow-box').addEventListener('scroll', evt => {
    evt.target.scrollTop = 0;
    evt.target.scrollLeft = 0;
});
```

Since I have a specific container that needs to prevent scroll, I'm using CSS to set `overflow: hidden` on it to trigger the issue on the container and not a parent element, and then I'm applying the JS above to prevent the scrolling.

This seems to be the best solution in my case.

If anyone knows of a simpler CSS solution, I will accept that answer over this one.

Comment: Scratching my head on this for a long time. This solution was the only one I could find which worked. My situation was a draggable dialog which can be dragged out of the bounds of its container, but I don't want the container to scroll if the text in the dialog runs off the screen, since the user can drag it back if they want to enter text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this what did you asking about:

1. if you need to solve problem of hidden content you only need to resize width at first and last selector
2. if you need to make text with scroll you can change type into text area and then defining rows and cols attribute, this should manage that.

If all of this does not help please add some picture of the expected result you need to make it clear.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, if I'm unclear. I added clarifying steps to reproduce and desired behavior if that helps. To answer your question, I don't want ANY scrolling at all, and I WANT the content to stay hidden. I just want the text cursor to disappear out of view with no side-effects. Thanks!